# OpenCV measure size of the centered object

Tags: android, opencv

I am having an issue with figuring out how to exactly implement algorithm to measure size pictured object in pixels using OpenCV library in my mobile application (it is needed as I know the real height of that object so to know the size in pixels I will be able to calculate distance)

I have not really found any information that would suit me.

The requirement that can be added to ease the problem is that the object must be placed in the middle of the image.

I am sorry in case it is a reposted problem.